# How to insert Buttons within a ListView in Android

Tags: android

How can i add button as items in a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

There are times when you have to put your own things like Buttons, icons, labels , textview etc in a ListView.

Well for that you would have to make your own custom ListView, extending Adapters. These custom ListView would have its own XML Layout file for static ListView Generation or you can also use it for dynamic generation as well.

I have learned about these custom ListView through various step by step tutorials. You can google it too.

I would recommend reading Sai Geetha's Blog. Its my personal favorite :). The Url is :
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

I would also recommend one more step by step tutorial :
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

I hope it helps :)